# change the order of output in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I want to solve a very simple system of linear equations. In the following codes, I want Matlab to present the solutions in order of a,b,c.

```
syms a b c
eqns = [a+b==0, a+2*c==0];
var1=[a,b,c];
[aSol,bSol,Ssol,param,conds]=solve(eqns, var1, 'ReturnConditions', true)
```

The following codes, which solves the same equations, but let Matlab to display solutions in order of b c a.

```
syms a b c
eqns = [a+b==0, a+2*c==0];
var2=[b,c,a];
[bSol,cSol,asol,param,conds]=solve(eqns, var2, 'ReturnConditions', true)
```

I'd like to combine these two codes by introducing a variable i: when i=1, the solutions are given in order of a,b,c and when i=2, the order is b,c,a.

I'm not quite familiar with Matlab's grammar. A pseudo-code I'm thinking is

```
var[1]=[a,b,c]; 
var[2]=[b,c,a];
s[1]=[aSol,bSol,Ssol,param,conds];
s[2]=[bSol,cSol,asol,param,conds];
i=1;
s[i]=solve(eqns, var[i], 'ReturnConditions', true)
```

I can change i to 2 if I want to change the order of the output. Can you help making the pseduo-code the real one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `var` as a matrix such that `var(i,:)` (`var[i]` in your pseduo-code ) corresponds to required order of variable.

For `s`, there is no need to define it. Just let it equal to the solution.

```
syms a b c
eqns = [a+b==0, a+2*c==0];
var(1,:) = [a,b,c];
var(2,:) = [b,c,a];

i = 1;

s = solve(eqns, var(i,:), 'ReturnConditions', true)
```

Here `s` is a [struct](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html). To access the solution of `a`, `b`, and `c`. You can do this:

```
s.a
s.b
s.c
```

Which gives

```
ans =
-2*z
ans =
2*z
ans =
z
```

Answer (score 1):

You could very simply change only the display, rather than the whole computation:

```
syms a b c
eqns = [a+b==0, a+2*c==0];
var1=[a,b,c];
[aSol,bSol,Ssol,param,conds]=solve(eqns, var1, 'ReturnConditions', true); % added semicolon
if i==1
   aSol,bSol,Ssol
else
   bSol,Ssol,aSol
end
```